# How to expire a collection register in DAYS or Months

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know that TTL (*time-to-live*) of a collection in mongodb can be done like this:

```
export const schema: Schema = new Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: 3600, <- HERE IN SECONDS!
  },
});
```

OR you could even run this:

```
currentSchema.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 3600});
```

Both examples are set in **SECONDS**. What if I want my *ttl* to be long like a year of 6 months?

Couldn't find anything on [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). Is there a way to set in other metric than seconds?

Comment: You can calculate how many seconds are in your desired TTL and pass that value.

Comment: Yeah I know. I was wondering if there is a way to use something else than seconds. Only seconds then.